# NSMutableCharacterSet addCharactersInString not supporting the space

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In the code below the string "(234) 567-4456" returns a range of (5,1).  Clearly the space is included in the character set.  (I don't want to allow all whitespace, just the real space.)  Does anyone know what's going on here?

```
cset = [NSMutableCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
[cset addCharactersInString:@"+.-() "];
[cset invert];
range = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:cset];
if (range.length != 0) {
    return InvalidString;
}
```

Comment: I get { NSNotFound, 0 } for the range with this code. :S

Comment: OK that supposed space was an 0x00A0.  It's called a "non-break space".  It wasn't found in the regex "\\s{2,}+".  What do you think NSGod?  Should I delete this question or leave it and make this comment my answer.